# Mist Multisig Wallet: How to change daily withdrawal limit?

Tags: wallets, mist, multisignature

Anybody know how to change a Mist multisig wallet's daily withdrawal limit from within Mist?

Comment: Would it not be better to not make this easier? Since for security reosons you would not want this to be easy to change right? I have a question, with a simple wallet I can change the daily limit easily, considering that a potential hacker would be able to do this as well is there still any point having this daily limit in place as a security measure? It would be better if this was harder to change or if there was some sort of timer involved with actually changing it?

Comment: Please ask your question separately.

Comment: this is a comment or a question not an answer

Comment: You need to repost your "answer" as a question...then I'm sure you'll get replies. Stackexchange is an online reference site, it isn't for the equivalent of forum posting in a thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I [talked with the wallet devs](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/162) and they said it's not easy to do yet, but they will be making it easy in a future release of the wallet software.

Answer (score 4):

I'd start off by saying it might not be possible. You might just have to transfer your funds into a new wallet contract. But if you're looking to try anyway...

Look into this function:

https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/master/Wallet.sol#L245

```
// (re)sets the daily limit. needs many of the owners to confirm. doesn't alter the amount already spent today.
function setDailyLimit(uint _newLimit) onlymanyowners(sha3(msg.data, block.number)) external {
    m_dailyLimit = _newLimit;
}
```

Please notice in the above that this is a onlymanyowners function. (If you had set it up as 2 of 3, I believe you'd need at least 2 of the keys to change the daily limit. Not sure this actually works like this, you'd want to test first.)

Comment: Right, that looks to be the code. Under "Show Contract Info" (a button clicked revealing content below it) in the Mist wallet page it has "Set Daily Limit" in the lower right column. I tried but must have done it wrong (just a test wallet for safety, no large amount of ETH in it). Looks possible, but no documentation yet (no surprise as it's early beta software).